# Trying to display the selection from a list in a different worksheet (text only)

Tags: excel-formula

I have a text list in one worksheet, and I would like to display the selection made from that list in another worksheet (same xl workbook). Most answers I have found seem very complicated, is this a difficult thing to do? Many thanks for your help!

Comment: when you say list, is it like a dropdown or combo box list?

Comment: Could you give an example of what exactly it is that you want to do, so that we can answer your question better? Maybe include a couple of screenshots if it will help.

Comment: Hi-- So, on sheet 1 I have the dropdown menu with 14 choices (i.e. "product 1" "product 2" etc.) These choices are stored in a table on sheet 2. On sheet 3 I would simply like to display the selection made on sheet 1 (i.e. "product 1"). I can show screenshots, but that may overcomplicate my question...

Comment: Solved it! I simply referenced the list cell on sheet 1 in a hidden column on sheet 1 and then referenced the hidden cell in sheet 3. Not elegant, but serviceable!

Answer (score 0):

OP has an answer but if the choice is made in A1 (of Sheet1) then in Sheet3:

```
=Sheet1!A1
```

would appear adequate.